# How to ensure the menu appears in the window's visible area

Tags: css, primefaces

I create a dynamic menu with primefaces submenu: , but if there are many menu items added, some of them cannot be showed in the visible area.

The menu area exceed the bottom of the web, so it cannot be showed. I want to know is there any solution to change the direction or position of the submenu?

Thanks a lot

Here my code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="bottom">
                            <p:tieredMenu position="dynamic" model="#{ServerGroupMgmtBean.model}" id="serverGroupMenu"/>
                            </td>
                            <td width="6"/>
                            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                            <p:commandButton id="dlgAddId" value="Add" oncomplete="dlgEditSG.show()" update=":editSGForm :smForm:messagePanel">
                              <f:param value="-1" name="editId"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: We would need a sample of the code you have, a link or a jsFiddle

Comment: You mean the visible area of the window or the visible area of the menu's parent container?

Comment: Sorry, I just come back from travel. Posted my code...